# PHP using XML Expat Parser

Tags: php, xml

It seems odd to me that when I ran my simple code, Expat Parser runs through top to bottom of given XML string. If there is different element with same name, like below, how can I create different handlers and assign them?

```
<car>
    <name>
    ...
</car>
<person>
    <name>
    ...
</person>
```

If I want `car>name` element and `person>name` element parse other way, how can I find the current element's parent?

Comment: I can't understand your want properly. Do you want to get parent of `car` and `person`?

Comment: I suggest using more modern XML APIs like XMLReader or DOM.